# How to use Incremental Loading Collection with CollectionViewSource to group list view items in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, listview, uwp

I followed up this example of [IncrementalLoadingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/incrementalloadingcollection) and created an app with Incremental Loading Collection (Infinite scrolling).

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="PeopleListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Person">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

C#:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PeopleSource : IIncrementalSource<Person>
{
    private readonly List<Person> people;

    public PeopleSource()
    {
        // Populate people
        ...
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPagedItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        // Gets and returns items from the collection according to pageIndex and pageSize parameters
        ...
    }
}    

var collection = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<PeopleSource, Person>();
PeopleListView.ItemsSource = collection;
```

[image]

But now I also need to group the items, for example, group by length of the name.
Separately, using this example of [CollectionViewSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource?view=winrt-20348), I created an example that what I expected to have:

XAML:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="groupInfoCVS" IsSourceGrouped="true" />
</Grid.Resources>
<ListView x:Name="PeopleListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupInfoCVS}}">
    ...
</ListView>
```

C#:

```
public string Name { get; set; }

// Populate people
...

var result =
from t in people
group t by t.Name.Length into g
orderby g.Key
select g;

groupInfoCVS.Source = result;
```

[image]

The problem is that I need to use Incremental Loading and group the items, I  can't find a way to use IncrementalLoadingCollection with CollectionViewSource.
Does anyone know how to do this or can suggest a solution?
Grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to use Incremental Loading Collection with CollectionViewSource to group list view items in UWP?

I have to say, `IncrementalLoadingCollection` does not work for `CollectionViewSource`. Both of the them work that need to be set as ListView's ItemsSource directly. Because they need to detect listview `Interaction`.

So for your requirement, we suggest listen listview `ViewChanged` and add more item manually.

For example

```
private void PeopleListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(PeopleListView.ItemsPanelRoot is ItemsStackPanel itemsStackPanel)) return;
    var _itemsStackPanel = itemsStackPanel;
    var _scrollViewer = MyFindDataGridChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(PeopleListView);
    // This event handler loads more items when scrolling.
    _scrollViewer.ViewChanged += (o, eventArgs) =>
    {
        if (eventArgs.IsIntermediate) return;
        double distanceFromBottom = itemsStackPanel.ActualHeight - _scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - _scrollViewer.ActualHeight;
        if (distanceFromBottom < 10) // 10 is an arbitrary number
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
            {
                var p = new Person { Name = "Person " + i };
                _people.Add(p);
                var result =
                            from t in _people
                            group t by t.Name.Length into g
                            orderby g.Key
                            select g;

                groupInfoCVS.Source = result;
                PeopleListView.ItemsSource = groupInfoCVS.View;
            }
        }
    };
}
```